# Regex/Notepad++ to extract text from file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have multiple files with text in parenthesis that I need to extract from the file (or delete everything else in that file).  I have a method that works, but it only works for one file.  Here is an example of the kind of files I'm dealing with.

```
(is it on?)
[3.87595  3.87595 0 ]xsh
grestore
NDTMRY+Helvetica[8.5 0 0 -8.5 0 0 ]msf
 mo
(NO)
```

The method I have used is as follows:

1. in notepad++ under the mark tab in find replace; Find: ^(.*?$ (with bookmark line checked)
2. Search>bookmarks>remove unbookmarked lines

Is there a way/better way to do this for multiple files at a time?  In this or another language such as python.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to do this to multiple files in notepad++. I would use python or C# to do this. Put the files in an array, and process each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to remove in multiple files lines that do not start with `(`.

Here is the screenshot with settings:

[image]

So, here are the instructions:

1. Press **Ctrl+H** and click *Find in Files*
2. In *Find What*, type `^(?!\().*\R*`, keep *Replace With* empty
3. Add file masks in *Filters*
4. Select the initial directory in *Directory*.
5. Make sure *Regular expression* radio button is selected.

Adjust other options and hit *Replace in Files* button.

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking at the problem backwards